# How to decide when to re-render/update an element in a Vuejs component?

Tags: vue.js

In the documentation [Edge-cases](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html), we talk about the **v-once** directive wish is helpful for heavy static content. But i'm surprised that other than this, we can't really decide for heavy and **NONE** static elements to re-render (there is the **vm.$forceUpdate** but it's really not what i'm looking for). For my use-case, that is not that much edgy..., i want to **NOT** re-render specific elements, like a large list of elements wish is heavy on performance, for every updates.

Adding the v-once directive make it that it will not be able to change after the first rendering. And if we wan't to come back and modify this list, it will not be possible.

I don't understand why this is not implemented since it can heavily increase performance.

We just need a prop, something like **v-trigger**, called by some **vm.triggers** to satisfy that need.

Please, is there at least some clear work around for this ?

Comment: If you're building your application right, a change one place shouldn't force the whole application to re-render. So as long as you aren't mutating the large list, it shouldn't change

Comment: @DerekPollard I'm not talking about the whole application, i'm just talking about a component.

Comment: Exactly, why would a component need to re-render or update if nothing has been changed on it?

Comment: For example if you have inside your component a huge list binded to a pretty big array and a little form that has no direct influence to that list. For every change on that form the whole list will be re-render for no specific needs. If you can decide to not rerender that specific list element other than with a v-once directives it would be a huge performance increase.

Comment: That means you're probably doing it wrong. The list should be in a separate component so it doesn't force a complete rerender

Comment: I think it would be easier if you explained the issue you are having... As @DerekPollard said - it all boils down to logic and how you have your app laid out.  For example, if you use a `method` in your `<template>`, while outputting user input in a 2-way binding, that method will be invoke on each key press... This is not how you should write something like this... [Here is an example of what I am referring to](https://jsfiddle.net/q3g59dca/3/)